# How to print one answer from two different inputs in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to the Python and stackoverflow community and would like some help on a particular problem I've been finding when writing my first "helloworld file".

The problem is that is that I can't find a way to print one answer from two different input string outcomes...

```
if information == ("Yes" or "yes") : #still trying to figure out how to make the program respond with "Ok" with both the inputs, "Yes" and "yes"
print('Ok')
print('Ok')
```

Any help/answers would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
if information == "Yes" or information == 'yes':
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can check for inclusion:

```
if information in ("Yes", "yes"):
    print('Ok')
```

or:

```
if information.lower() == "yes":
    print('Ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if information == "Yes" or information == "yes":
    print('Ok')
    print('Ok')
```

or

```
if information in ('yes', 'Yes', 'YES'):
    print('Ok')
    print('Ok')
```

another way is:

```
if information.lower() == "yes":
    print('Ok')
    print('Ok')
```

or a lazy way:

```
if information.lower().startwith("y"):
    print('Ok')
    print('Ok')
```

Hope it work as expected